# Show a text field dialog without being covered by keyboard?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a `SimpleDialog` that allows the user to enter their name.  But when it is displayed the dialog is half hidden by the on-screen keyboard:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get the `Dialog` to be fully visible?

Edit: I find it strange that the homepage widget (FocusVisibilityDemo) recognises the reduced height and therefore adjusts the position of the 'Push Me' button to remain in the center.  Unfortunately the dialog doesn't behave the same way.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FocusVisibilityDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FocusVisibilityDemoState createState() => new _FocusVisibilityDemoState();
}

class _FocusVisibilityDemoState extends State<FocusVisibilityDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Text Dialog Demo')),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _showDialog,
          child: new Text("Push Me"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showDialog() async {
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      child: new AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        content: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Full Name', hintText: 'eg. John Smith'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('CANCEL'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('OPEN'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new FocusVisibilityDemo()));
}
```

Comment: You may want to use a full screen typing in this case.

Comment: @Mark How to get the value which is entered in the textfield?

Comment: @ArgaPK You should instantiate a TextEditingController instance, and pass it to your TextField's 'controller' parameter. Then, setup 'onSubmitted' method of your TextField, it's a method which will be called when you hit 'OK' and it has a String parameter - that is your data entered in the TextField. You can also setup 'onChanged' method, so every time you entered something in the TextField, 'onChanged' will be called.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If your use case is to add multiple `TextFields` inside your `Dialog` so your main `Form` does not get crowded, I think it is better if you build something more customizable than `AlertDialog` and `SimpleDialog` as they are used for simple activities (confirmations, radios..etc).

Otherwise, why do you want to use a `Dialog` for a single `TextField` ?

When we add multiple `TextField`s we should be careful about our design choices since other people will interact with this view to fill in the data, in this case I prefer to use `fullscreenDialog` property of [`PageRoute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRoute-class.html) class. I am not sure if `SimpleDialog` can be suitable for that in Flutter.

Here is a quick example on how to use a `FullScreenDialog`, I hope this help and you should be able to modify it the way you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FullScreenDialog _myDialog = new FullScreenDialog();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Fill this form"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(controller: new TextEditingController(
                text: "Add a single text field"),),

            new Card(child: new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Click to add your top 3 amazing skills"),
              subtitle: new Text(
                  "${_myDialog._skillOne} ${_myDialog._skillTwo} ${_myDialog
                      ._skillThree}"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => _myDialog,
                  fullscreenDialog: true,
                ));
              },
            ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

}


class FullScreenDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  String _skillOne = "You have";
  String _skillTwo = "not Added";
  String _skillThree = "any skills yet";

  @override
  FullScreenDialogState createState() => new FullScreenDialogState();
}

class FullScreenDialogState extends State<FullScreenDialog> {
  TextEditingController _skillOneController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _skillTwoController = new TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController _skillThreeController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Add your top 3 skills"),
        ),
        body: new Padding(child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(controller: _skillOneController,),
            new TextField(controller: _skillTwoController,),
            new TextField(controller: _skillThreeController,),
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                  widget._skillThree = _skillThreeController.text;
                  widget._skillTwo = _skillTwoController.text;
                  widget._skillOne = _skillOneController.text;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }, child: new Text("Save"),))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ), padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),)
    );
  }


}
```

**EDIT**

After doing some research, it seems that [this is a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7032) in the current Flutter version, the temporary fix is also documented in this issue.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new FocusVisibilityDemo()));
}

class FocusVisibilityDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FocusVisibilityDemoState createState() => new _FocusVisibilityDemoState();
}


class _FocusVisibilityDemoState extends State<FocusVisibilityDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Text Dialog Demo')),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _showDialog,
          child: new Text("Push Me"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showDialog() async {
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      child: new _SystemPadding(child: new AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        content: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Full Name', hintText: 'eg. John Smith'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('CANCEL'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('OPEN'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}


class _SystemPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  _SystemPadding({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return new AnimatedContainer(
        padding: mediaQuery.viewInsets,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        child: child);
  }
}
```

Comment: No I don't want to add multiple text fields - I simply want the user to enter one text value.  A dialog is appropriate in my case because it keeps the screen clean and minimal.  Let me explain: imagine a home screen for a game that has two buttons: 'Create a New Game' and 'Access a Shared Game'.  When the user clicks the second button the app asks the user to type the unique ID for the game that the user wants to access.

Comment: My bad, I found this issued as a bug, check the edited section in the answer.

Comment: Thanks - the _SystemPadding workaround is working fine for me!

Comment: `padding: mediaQuery.padding,` needs to be changed to `padding: mediaQuery.viewInsets,`

Comment: @aziza How to get the value which is entered in the textfield?

Comment: it shows black screen if we opened it from StatefulWidget while click on any button

Comment: To get the value of the `TextField`, a `TextEditingController` can be used. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Comment: Great example. @ArgaPK To get the value back using simple callback function reference https://gist.github.com/pravynandas/11e6db379b5ce2bf27dd72d903a8e8ae

Comment: Is this still a bug in 2022?