# Flutter : Alert Dialog hide by keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I have form inside AlertDialog.I have problem about Keyboard hide my AlertDialog.

I'm already follow another question include [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841637/show-a-text-field-dialog-without-being-covered-by-keyboard?fbclid=IwAR3a6SsMwlwBaYmm4Gr8zISmZRkbXSTQOsv7vxDnf4eCOKsZRd77zjcEV20) and [This issue Form Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7032?fbclid=IwAR0jS3TLFEVb-j8QYm33iZzZROA1kAOcTJgPSYnc39hHEoyOOB1wl4zWGVg), But it's not solved my problem.

I also try using wrap my AlertDialog with `SingleChildScrollView` ,But Position AlertDialog on Top Screen.

I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

## Edit Source Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeNamed = "/testing-page";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => showDialog(
          child: CustomAlertDialog(
            //  controller: _txtUserController,
            title: "Description About You",
            labelText: "Fill Your Name",
            errorTextEmpty: "Provided Name",
            //  boxName: "user_box",
            //  userModelHive: UserModelHive()
            //    ..id = DateTime.now()
            //    ..giverName = _txtUserController.text
            //    ..pinCodeNumber = "",
            //  routeName: HomeScreen.routeNamed,
          ),
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
        ),
        child: Text('Open Dialog'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String title;
  final String labelText;
  final String errorTextEmpty;
  final String boxName;

//  final UserModelHive userModelHive;
  final String routeName;

  CustomAlertDialog({
    this.controller,
    this.title,
    this.labelText,
    this.errorTextEmpty,
    this.boxName,
    //  this.userModelHive,
    this.routeName,
  });

  @override
  _CustomAlertDialogState createState() => _CustomAlertDialogState();
}

class _CustomAlertDialogState extends State<CustomAlertDialog> {
//  final Repository _repository = Repository();
  final formKeys = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKeys,
      child: _SystemPadding(
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          content: TextFormField(
            controller: widget.controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: widget.labelText,
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return widget.errorTextEmpty;
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                label: const Text("Let's go"),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SystemPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  _SystemPadding({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    print(mediaQuery.viewInsets.bottom);
    return AnimatedContainer(
      padding: mediaQuery.padding,
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please just wrap your alert dialog with `SingleChildScrollView`

example

```
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(child: alert);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `_SystemPadding` class, while returning `AnimatedContainer`, use `padding` as `mediaQuery.padding` that'll adjust the height of the `alertDialog` and no need to wrap `alertDialog` content with `SingleChildScrollView`. Working code below:

```
class _SystemPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  _SystemPadding({this.child});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return new AnimatedContainer(
        padding: mediaQuery.padding,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        child: child);
  }
}

void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: _SystemPadding(
        child: CustomAlertDialog(
          // controller: _txtUserController,
          title: "Description About You",
          labelText: "Fill Your Name",
          errorTextEmpty: "Provided Name",
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Output: It scrolls up the dialog appropriately when keyboard opens:

[image]

This way the alertDialog doesn't move at the top, but adjusts itself to be considerably above the keyboard.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Nothing happens after change `mediaQuery.viewInset` to `mediaQuery.padding`. Dialog still hide by keyboard.

Comment: I used your updated code and was able to see alert dialog scrolling up properly when keyboard opens. I just commented out some of your code which I don't know what represents e.g `PageViewContent` which your wrapped above `CustomAlertDialog`. For demo, I used a `RaisedButton` upon tapping on it calls `showDialog`.  Also, I kept the `padding: mediaQuery.padding,` inside `AnimatedContainer`.  Here's my full demo code which works well for me. Hope it helps to resolve your issue.  https://codeshare.io/2Eqllv

Comment: Oke , i getting confused. I don't know why it's still not working although i follow try your code. it's still hide the dialog.
https://gist.github.com/zgramming/d98724c3241c441f926c7d8982b64498
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su4Fo.gif